# Pointwise convergence of $f_n(x) = \sqrt{n}x^2(1 - x^3)^n$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n(x) = \sqrt{n}x^2(1 - x^3)^n$

At $x = 0$ and $x = 1$, $f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

However for $0 < x < 1$,

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n}x^2(1 - x^3)^n$

= $x^2 \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n} \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}(1 - x^3)^n$

= $x^2 * \infty * 0$

= undefined

So this sequence of functions doens't converge pointwise? Is this correct? I put the following into wolfram alpha to get an idea of what's happening geometrically -

> plot sqrt(1) * x * (1 - x^2)^1, sqrt(5000) * x * (1 - x^2)^5000 on
>   [0,1]

It 'looks' like it converges pointwise...so did I mistake above? How should I interpret the geometric view of what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

For $0<x<1$ we have that $f_n(x)\to 0$ because for a $0<θ<1$ we have that $n^kθ^n\to 0$ for every $k\in \Bbb Z$. Here $\sqrt n x^2(1-x^3)^n>0$ and $x^{2/n}(1-x^3)<θ<1$ for every $n$ ,for some $θ$ and thus $(x^{2/n}(1-x^3))^n<θ^n<1$. So $\sqrt n x^2(1-x^3)^n<n^k x^2(1-x^3)^n<n^kθ^n\to 0$ for some $k\in \Bbb N$.

Comment: @csss ,check my proof please.thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can't so easily interchange the limit and the product!
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\big( \sqrt{n}(1-x^3)^n \big) \neq \big(\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n} \big)\big(\lim_{n\to \infty} (1-x^3)^n \big)
$$
since, as you pointed out, the latter doesn't make sense. If $x \in (0,1)$, how about let $x^3 = 1-\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ and use L'Hopital type arguments to find what 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \big( \sqrt{n} \epsilon^n \big) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\epsilon^{-n}}\right)
$$
turns out to be.

Comment: When I apply L'Hopitals rule to that I end up with $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} - \frac{\epsilon^n}{2 \sqrt{n}log(\epsilon)} = \frac{0}{\infty}$ which is still indeterminate so it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: $\frac{0}{\infty}$ is not indeterminate, it's $0$. Since $\epsilon^n \to 0$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0$, both converge to $0$ and $0 \cdot 0 = 0$.